Reposting the stored notificaions in React Native using Kotlin Native modules
I'm developing an Android app where I need to block and then repost notifications. My app successfully blocks notifications, but when I try to repost them, they don't appear in the status bar. I have added logging to confirm that the repost method is called and executed without errors.
Here are the relevant parts of my code:
MyNotificationListener class:
package com.blissio_ai_frontend

import android.app.Notification
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Build
import android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService
import android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification
import android.util.Log

class MyNotificationListener : NotificationListenerService() {
    companion object {
        var BLOCK_ALL: Boolean = false
        val blockedAppPackages: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
        private const val TAG = "MyNotificationListener"
        val blockedNotifications: MutableList<StatusBarNotification> = mutableListOf()
        private lateinit var context: Context

        fun initialize(context: Context) {
            this.context = context
        }
    }

    override fun onNotificationPosted(sbn: StatusBarNotification) {
        val notification: Notification = sbn.notification
        val packageName: String = sbn.packageName
        val title: CharSequence? = notification.extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE)
        val text: CharSequence? = notification.extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT)

        Log.d(TAG, "Notification from: $packageName, Title: $title, Text: $text")

        if (BLOCK_ALL) {
            cancelAllNotifications()
            Log.d(TAG, "All notifications blocked")
            storeBlockedNotification(sbn)
        } else {
            if (blockedAppPackages.contains(packageName)) {
                cancelNotification(sbn.key)
                Log.d(TAG, "Notification from $packageName blocked")
                storeBlockedNotification(sbn)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onNotificationRemoved(sbn: StatusBarNotification) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification removed: ${sbn.packageName}")
    }

    private fun storeBlockedNotification(sbn: StatusBarNotification) {
        blockedNotifications.add(sbn)
    }

    fun getBlockedNotifications(): String {
        return blockedNotifications.joinToString(separator = "\n") { sbn ->
            val packageName = sbn.packageName
            val title = sbn.notification.extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE)
            val text = sbn.notification.extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT)
            "Package: $packageName, Title: $title, Text: $text"
        }
    }

   fun repostBlockedNotifications() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Reposting blocked notifications")
        val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                "default_channel",
                "Default Channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            )
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

        blockedNotifications.forEach { sbn ->
            val originalNotification = sbn.notification
            val repostedNotificationBuilder = Notification.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle(originalNotification.extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE))
                .setContentText(originalNotification.extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT))
                .setWhen(originalNotification.`when`)
                .setShowWhen(true)
                .setChannelId(originalNotification.channelId ?: "default_channel")
                .setSmallIcon(context.applicationInfo.icon)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setAutoCancel(true)

            val repostedNotification = repostedNotificationBuilder.build()
            Log.d(TAG, "Reposting notification with ID: ${System.currentTimeMillis().toInt()}")
            notificationManager.notify(System.currentTimeMillis().toInt(), repostedNotification)
        }
    }
}

And this is my notification module:
package com.blissio_ai_frontend

import android.util.Log
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.provider.Settings
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Promise
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod

class NotificationModule(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext) : ReactContextBaseJavaModule(reactContext) {
    private val context: ReactApplicationContext = reactContext

    init {
        MyNotificationListener.initialize(context)
    }

    override fun getName(): String {
        return "NotificationModule"
    }

    @ReactMethod
    fun openNotificationSettings() {
        val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }

    @ReactMethod
    fun setBlockAllNotifications(block: Boolean) {
        MyNotificationListener.BLOCK_ALL = block
    }

    @ReactMethod
    fun blockNotificationsForApp(packageName: String, block: Boolean) {
        if (block) {
            MyNotificationListener.blockedAppPackages.add(packageName)
        } else {
            MyNotificationListener.blockedAppPackages.remove(packageName)
        }
    }

    @ReactMethod
    fun setDoNotDisturb(enable: Boolean, promise: Promise) {
        val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        if (notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted) {
            notificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(
                if (enable) NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE
                else NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALL
            )
            promise.resolve(true)
        } else {
            promise.reject("PERMISSION_DENIED", "Notification policy access is not granted")
        }
    }

    @ReactMethod
    fun getBlockedNotifications(promise: Promise) {
        val listener = MyNotificationListener()
        val blockedNotifications = listener.getBlockedNotifications()
        Log.d("NotificationModule", "Blocked Notifications: $blockedNotifications")
        promise.resolve(blockedNotifications)
    }

    @ReactMethod
    fun repostBlockedNotifications(promise: Promise) {
        try {
            val listener = MyNotificationListener()
            listener.repostBlockedNotifications()
            promise.resolve(true)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("NotificationModule", "Error reposting notifications", e)
            promise.reject("ERROR_REPOSTING", "Failed to repost notifications")
        }
    }
}

This is my javascript code:
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, Button, StyleSheet, Text, ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';

const {NotificationModule} = NativeModules;

const openNotificationAccessSettings = () => {
  NotificationModule.openNotificationAccessSettings();
};

const setDoNotDisturb = (enable: boolean) => {
  NotificationModule.setBlockAllNotifications(enable);

  console.log('Navigated to notification settings for Facebook.');
};

const getBlockedNotifications = async () => {
  try {
    const notifications = await NotificationModule.getBlockedNotifications();
    console.log('Blocked notifications:', notifications);

    // Repost the blocked notifications
    const repostResult = await NotificationModule.repostBlockedNotifications();
    console.log('Repost result:', repostResult);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error retrieving or reposting blocked notifications', error);
  }
};

const NotificationSettings: React.FC = () => {
  const [blockedNotifications, setBlockedNotifications] = useState<string>('');

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button
        title="Open Notification Access Settings"
        onPress={openNotificationAccessSettings}
      />

      <Button
        title="Enable Do Not Disturb"
        onPress={() => setDoNotDisturb(true)}
      />
      <Button
        title="Disable Do Not Disturb"
        onPress={() => setDoNotDisturb(false)}
      />
      <Button
        title="Get Blocked Notifications"
        onPress={getBlockedNotifications}
      />
      <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
        <Text>{blockedNotifications}</Text>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  scrollView: {
    marginTop: 20,
    padding: 10,
    width: '100%',
  },
});

export default NotificationSettings;

This is the relevant logcat output:
All notifications blocked
Notification removed: com.facebook.katana
Reposting blocked notifications
Reposting notification with ID: 1756651103
Notification from: com.google.android.setupwizard, Title: اتمام راه‌اندازی ‏Xperia™‎‏, Text: کپی کردن داده‌ها،  و چند دلیل دیگر
All notifications blocked

